# What to choose for a multilingual site with support for Markdown and commenting

Tags: domains, looking-for-a-script, drupal, multilingual, markdown

I want to publish articles at a multilingual site.

1. I want to be able to write an article in two languages and have them available on separate URLs:

   - thesite.foo/english-breakfast
   - thesite.com/engelsk-frukost
2. If the users web browser is set to English I'd like to show a small notice at the top of the Swedish version with a link to the English one. The link should have an appropriate rel attribute for a translation (search for hreflang at http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html).
3. There should be a way to list all articles belonging to these sets: Swedish only, English only, Swedish versions + English only, English versions + Swedish only. I'd like to publish these as four RSS-feeds. And I would like to have two versions of the main site, one in Swedish (showing Swedish versions + English only) and one in English (showing English versions).
4. I shall be able to write the articles using Markdown, as that is the formatting language I find most convenient.
5. There should be a way for users to comment. And some kind of way for me to protect myself against comment spam.

I am leaning towards learning Drupal. I suspect I'll have to code this behavior myself as a module. To be frank I'd rather work with Java. Is Drupal the way to go? Or is there something more suitable for this project?

Answer (score 1):

**With WordPress:**

After installing WordPress, download this plugin and play with it. It should be able to do everything you need (look at the plugin description to judge):

[qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/)

**With Drupal:**

Drupal is a great CMS. When a client of mine needed multi-lingual/localized content, I used Drupal. There are modules for translation and localization, and the instructions on those modules will teach you more than I could just by typing it out here.

Check out modules for Drupal here:

[Drupal Modules](http://drupalmodules.com)

On that site, if you choose the category "multilingual" from the top, you'll get tons of modules you can go through, all rated and reviewed and for free use with Drupal. Tons of information, everything you could need, for sure.

I'm a Drupal/WordPress developer and designer, and I'm pretty sure the WordPress option would be much easier and user-friendly for you... but either route you take, you'll be fine!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I use Wordpress with the plug in [WPML (Wordpress Multilingual)](http://wpml.org/) for every multilingual site i build for my clients. Its amazing!

Especially if you pay for the pro version. Then you can even create translator users and rent professional translators directly through the plug inn interface!

the best thing about it is that it has allot of options while mentaining an easy to use interface.